# geodata reconciliation with OpenRefine using longitude and latitude

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude, openrefine, geonames, database-reconciliation

I have a xls table containing a column with long lat information: for example "60.974387; 25.6472465" and i would like to reconcile that information in Openrefine to get the name of that place (or nearest place)

Does anyone know a reconciliation service? and the link to it?
Many thanks,
Tim

Comment: That process is called "geocoding." Googling that with OpenRefine should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's this (https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities) if you want to do the match outside of Openrefine (e.g. database queries)